# Standard boolean order of operation

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic, operator-precedence

I'm writing a shunting yard algorithm in Javascript for boolean logic, and I'm running into a hitch with order of operations. The operations that I allow are:

```
and, or, implies, equals(biconditional), not, xor, nor, nand
```

However, I don't know what the precedence is for these. As of now, I have:

```
not>equals>implies>xor>nor>nand>or>and
```

Is this correct? Is there any standard I can use, similar to the PEMDAS/BODMAS system for numbers?

Comment: Going by the Coq proof assistant, not > equals > xor > and > and > or > implies

Comment: The C standard uses NOT > EQUALS > AND > XOR > OR. To make precedence parsing work, unary operators should have higher priority than all binary operators. AND is generally considered to bind tighter than OR, allowing one to implement expressions in Canonical Disjunctive Form with no parentheses: `( A && B || C && D )`.

Comment: Since you like the Shunting Yard algorithm, you might also like [precedence climbing](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having such a hard time finding a definition of precedence of those operators for JavaScript is that:

1. Precedence only comes into play when using infix notation. Since you mention the shunting yard algorithm I take you intend to use infix notation.
2. Each language can define it's own precedence and since you are creating a DSL, you create the precedence, but it must be consistent.
3. Those names are really prefix function names and infix is more common with symbols for operators than names. You should be using operators and not function names:

> and                        &
>   or                         |
>   implies                    →
>   equals (biconditional)     ↔
>   not                        !
>   xor                        ⊕
>   nor                        ⊽
>   nand                       ⊼
>
> When parsing you convert infix to prefix or postfix, so the operators symbols should change to function names if you are building an intermediate form such as an AST.
>
> You didn't mention [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) which you will need for NOT.
>
> There appears to be no standard as noted by the differences between these two respectable sources.

From ["Foundations of Computer Science"](http://i.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs/ch12.pdf) by Jeffrey D. Ullman

**Associativity and Precedence of Logical Operators**

The order of precedence we shall use is
1. NOT (highest)
2. NAND
3. NOR
4. AND
5. OR
6. IMPLIES 
7. BICONDITIONAL(lowest)

From [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)

NOT
AND
NAND
XOR
OR
NOR
EQUIVALENT
IMPLIES

Answer (score 0):

It's seems there is no a standart.

I've a book ([Digital design by Morris Mano](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Digital_design.html?id=CkL61_UP6XoC&redir_esc=y)) that says `NOT>AND>OR`. this is an accepted opinion.

About the rest, i've found few opinions.
[This guy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128504/boolean-algebra-operation-precedence) think `EQUIV` is the lowest ([Wikipedia assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence)). but [this guy](http://teacherweb.com/MD/ReservoirHighSchool/Hahne/Boolean-Algebra.pdf) think `EQUIV` is in the middle `XOR>EQUIV>OR` (with few references).

Another disagreement is about `XOR` place. here [this third guy](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/res/boolean-algebra-laws/boolean-algebra-laws.pdf) agree with the second guy :)

In short, two opinions:

1) `NOT>AND>NAND>XOR>EQUIV>OR>NOR` (ignoring `NOR`)

2) `NOT>AND>NAND>NOR>OR>IMPLIES>XOR>EQUIV`

Note: only the `NOT>AND>OR` part is certified academically.