# Javascript If statement containing both AND ( && ) and OR ( || )

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I am puzzled why this statement evaluates to true:

```
(false && true || true) === true;
```

If the AND (`&&`) is a guard and the boolean proceeding it is false then it should have broken out of the if statement there, yet it doesn't and goes on to evaluate the OR (`||`) statement.

I had to do:

```
false && (true || true) === false;
```

to get the desired outcome. Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Basic [operator precidence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table)

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the first is equivalent to `((false && true) || true)`

Comment: `(false && true || true)` => `(false || true)` => `true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard boolean order of operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147722/standard-boolean-order-of-operation)

Comment: @user3146945 In `a && b || c`, the right operand of `&&` is `b`, not `b || c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

`(false && true || true) === true` becomes:

`(false || true) === true` becomes:

`(true) === true`

Comment: I was thinking that once it hit the false && -- evaluation stopped and broke out of the conditional. Hence, why it is sometimes referred to as a guard. Thanks for your patience.